# What is potential value of an additional pointing domain?

Tags: seo, search-results, multiple-domains

We have an opportunity to buy an extra domain that is quite specific to what we do and where we do it e.g. newyorkplumber.com.

This domain will just point to our current business's website url which is our business's name : fooplumber.biz

Does this new domain have any chance of showing up on search results if someone searches for "New York plumber"?

Is it worth while to buy additional pointing / forwarding domains if they are very specific to our business i.e. does it have potential to bring us any additional traffic?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28784310/1591669).

Answer (score 2):

We get these questions from time to time. Adding another domain name does practically nothing for you. There is relatively no domain name keyword advantage, no usability advantage, and no real reason to spend more money. You are always far better off making your current domain name perform as well as it can. The one option I tell people to think about is this. If your current site is fairly new and there really is only a little cost to transfer the content to a new domain name, then consider doing that. Otherwise, I always recommend that people think twice about changing domain names or adding others into the mix. It simply does not make sense in most situations. There is no trick to making your site perform better except improving the site itself. Nothing you can do externally short of back links will have any real effect. I say unless your company is new and your site is new, then put your wallet back in your pocket and worry about other things.